# Use of preposition with 'adopted' in a sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Can this machine be adopted______farm work?

Options were:
a)in
b)into
c)for
d)by

Please provide the correct answer with proper explanation.

Comment: Did the source say *adopted*, or did it say *adapted*?

Comment: I think it would be "clumsy" *whichever* preposition you put in there. Most likely the writer (test-setter?) has mangled the more natural *Can this machine be **adapted** for/to farm work?* But he would be an *inexperienced / incompetent* test-setter, since there's no justification for supposing there could be a single unambiguously correct answer.

Comment: If that's a multiple-choice test question, why not cite it fully, please? Otherwise, where did it come from?

Either way, given those specific choices the *best* answer would be "Can this machine be adopted *for* farm work" but that doesn't make it a good question, nor much of a useful one.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition "for" would be the best option, based on the etymology of the word.
Adopt = "chose for oneself, take by choice, select".